# semantic-ui dropdown menu disabled item

Tags: semantic-ui

I wonder if there is a way to make one item in a dropdown menu disabled, e.g. not selectable?
Jade markup:

```
.ui.dropdown
    span.text My Menu
    i.dropdown.icon
    .menu
       .item 1
       .item 2
       .item 3
```

Say, item 3 should be not possible to select?

Answer (score 4):

In order to disable a dropdown, use `disabled` class:

```
<div class="ui disabled dropdown">
  Disabled dropdown <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <!-- Any subsequent options are not available -->
  </div>
</div>
```

It also works for individual options:

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
  Dropdown <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Choice 1</div>
    <div class="disabled item">Choice 2</div>
    <div class="item">Choice 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/akhanov/zrbyqetz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is coming in SUI 2.0